# How do I find out where this CSS-value comes from?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip for something it probably wasn't designed for, namely the possibility of showing a quite large text. I have managed to tweek it to my needs, with one exception. The width of the text box shown is way too narrow, unless i set it to a fixed width, but then it looks awfully stupid when displaying my short texts. I did override the standard max-width of 200px, but still it would not display even any wider than 120.797px

I tried to make a short simple example, and to my surprise, it works perfectly in my fiddle. with no `width` property set, it still grows to `800px`, as set in `max-width`. So I tried to figure out what was different between my simple fiddle, and my larger web page. I used the google chrome dev-tools, to show me all set css properties, as I expected some unknown source to influence the `width`. Normally all properties set by css, are displayed with an arrow on the left side of each property, telling you exactly where, and through which file and selector statement this property is set. Here is what I found:

[image]

So, every other property gives a reference, while width remains a mysterious unknown. Notice that the font color is dark red. If this was calculated from other properties, it normally would be faded. I've tried to research what this might mean, but the official documentation leaves no clues. [This page was the closest thing I could find](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference).

**How do I find out where this CSS-value comes from?**

[Here is a link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcpbfvz3/). The tooltip text is a random news source from today, in norwegian. Code below, as per Stackoverflow rules:

HTML:

```
<span class="nav-text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="– Vi har nok satt oss litt i respekt i dag for de andre nasjonene. De vet nå at vi ikke er uredde og ikke er redd for å bare gå fra dem i front, sa Johannes Thingnes Bø om den solide seieren.

For da Emil Hegle Svendsen sendte Johannes Thingnes Bø ut på den siste etappen sammen med franske Antonin Guigonnat og italienske Therry Chenal var det mye som skulle gå galt for at ikke stryningen skulle sikre norsk stafettseier.

Og stryningen gikk knallhardt ut og viste konkurrentene ryggen allerede i den første motbakken.

– Jeg er ganske trygg og selvsikker når jeg går ut på siste etappe, sa ankermannen til NRK etter målgang.

En god generalprøve før OL
Det var et godt fornøyd stafettlag etter seieren. Stafetten i Ruhpolding var den store generalprøven for det som skal være det norske OL-laget i Pyeongchang i februar.

– Det var en god følelse. Jeg tar gjerne samme løpsopplegg neste gang det er stafett, sa Thingnes Bø etter seieren med et klart hint til stafetten i OL.">
    Hover for tooltip
</span>
```

CSS:

```
div.tooltip{
    top:0px !important;
}

div.tooltip>div.tooltip-arrow{
    top:15px !important;
}

div.tooltip>div.tooltip-inner{
    max-width:800px !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And standard init of bootstrap tooltip, javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Your HTML has a `span` your css has `div.` is that just a typo?

Comment: No, actually, but I understand the confusion. The div referenced in the css is generated by the javascript.